# Json object field as numeric in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

```
{
"All Day Menu":[{
    "id": "2",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "name": "Veg",
    "menu_id": "1",
    "categories": [{
        "id": "822",
        "description": "",
        "image": "",
        "name": "Veg Items",
        "menu_mcat_id": "2",
        "items": {
            "631836": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "631836",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Shahi paneer",
                    "menu_cat_id": "822",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195420",
                    "price": "160",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "631838": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "631838",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Kali mirch paneer",
                    "menu_cat_id": "822",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195422",
                    "price": "160",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "name": "Non-Veg",
    "menu_id": "1",
    "categories": [{
        "id": "9078",
        "description": "",
        "image": "",
        "name": "Chicken Items",
        "menu_mcat_id": "4",
        "items": {
            "1246892": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1246892",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Butter chicken",
                    "menu_cat_id": "9078",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195424",
                    "price": "380",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1246894": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1246894",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Kadhai chicken",
                    "menu_cat_id": "9078",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195426",
                    "price": "380",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1246896": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1246896",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Masala chicken",
                    "menu_cat_id": "9078",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195428",
                    "price": "380",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "name": "Roti-Naan",
    "menu_id": "1",
    "categories": [{
        "id": "16490",
        "description": "",
        "image": "indian-breads-roti02-jpg",
        "name": "Indian Breads",
        "menu_mcat_id": "12",
        "items": {
            "1540012": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1540012",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Chapati",
                    "menu_cat_id": "16490",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195430",
                    "price": "8",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1540014": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1540014",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Butter chapati",
                    "menu_cat_id": "16490",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195432",
                    "price": "15",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1540016": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1540016",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Naan",
                    "menu_cat_id": "16490",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195434",
                    "price": "20",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1540018": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1540018",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Butter naan",
                    "menu_cat_id": "16490",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195436",
                    "price": "30",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1540020": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1540020",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Laccha paratha",
                    "menu_cat_id": "16490",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195438",
                    "price": "25",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            },
            "1540022": {
                "standard": {
                    "id": "1540022",
                    "restid": "4806",
                    "menu_id": "1",
                    "name": "Kali mirch laccha paratha",
                    "menu_cat_id": "16490",
                    "description": null,
                    "image": "",
                    "posItemID": "0",
                    "video_url": "",
                    "option_id": "1195440",
                    "price": "30",
                    "start_date": "2007-06-01",
                    "end_date": null,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:00",
                    "has_options": "0",
                    "calories": null,
                    "packaging": "0",
                    "size": "standard",
                    "popular": null
                }
            }
        }
     }]
}}
}
```

I am using inbuilt Json library from android docs. I have been in successful parsing till categories array after which I am stuck here at items:{ "numeric value". I have created an Object of Item but after that I am unable to retrieve value. How should I proceed regarding this any help would be much appreciated. P.S cannot use Jackson or Gson parser as everything else depends on the current parser which I am using.

Comment: where is you "numeric value" called and what is the response getting when retrieve value

Comment: @sree Response is the rest of the data after I create item as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I understood your question, but you can use the `keys` method to get an iterator that allows you to enumerate the keys in the "items" object.

The code would look similar to this:

```
JSONObject items = ...;
Iterator itemIter = items.keys();
while (itemIter.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String)itemIter.next();
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(key);
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

If it gives you an `Enumeration` back you are most likely not using `org.json`. Try to exchange the `Iterator` for an `Enumeration`:

```
JSONObject items = ...;
Enumeration itemEnum = items.keys();
while (itemEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String)itemEnum.nextElement();
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(key);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did that but I keep on getting error message cannot convert Enumeration to iterator.

Comment: @Sutirth See my update. Should work if you use `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: It worked thnx a ton/heaps cant thank you enough. A one more query how should I proceed with standard object??

Comment: There is nothing special with it, you can access the individual fields with `getString`: for example `standards.getString("id")` and so on.

Comment: Actually I wrote one more nested while loop for accessing standard elements . Thnx once again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator for parsing dynamically generated json: Following is the code i am using for my project:

```
JSONObject responseJsonObject = obj.getJSONArray("items");
int size = responseJsonObject.length();
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
Jsonobject temp = responseJsonObject.getItemAtIndex(i);
Iterator keys = temp.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String curKey = (String) keys.next();
            String curValue = responseJsonObject.getString(curKey);
            AppData.listCityId.add(curKey);
            AppData.listCityName.add(curValue);
            // Log.d("key", curKey+ "  "+curValue);
        }
```

}

Please note that I am showing only how to parse dynamic json.

Comment: The thing is mine "items" is not array its an object have a look at the json carefully hence this wont work :(

Comment: May be the code i posted might not work but the same technique will work. String curKey = (String) keys.next(); This line inside the field takes care of the Json tag you need to access the values. Just give it a try.

Comment: 1st) I have to take my item as an object not as an array hence 1st part is not working :( and secondly the Iterator gives me mismatch error cannot convert Enumeration to iterator.

Comment: it is valid hence i could parse before till categories array Henry solution worked for me I am just trying to figure out rest now.